# Is that possible to design a div with css3 shadow + gradient + rounded corners in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm trying to have for my IE div's the same behavior than with other browsers. I have this css :

```
#featured .Reasons{
    height:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding:35px;
    display:block;

    background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(245,243,233) 48%, rgb(255,255,255) 79%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(245,243,233) 48%, rgb(255,255,255) 79%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(245,243,233) 48%, rgb(255,255,255) 79%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(245,243,233) 48%, rgb(255,255,255) 79%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(245,243,233) 48%, rgb(255,255,255) 79%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, rgb(255,255,255)),
        color-stop(0.48, rgb(245,243,233)),
        color-stop(0.79, rgb(255,255,255))
    );

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;

    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

It works fine with every browser but IE. I know IE is a bit special(hmm let s say annoying) in term of design, but How can I fix that ?
You can see it here : [stringtheori.es](https://stringtheori.es)
 Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used css3Pie before and its good. But be sure to read the known issues so you can make a good decision on whether you think you can use it or not.

http://css3pie.com/about/

Comment: yeah but IE isn't supposed to understand that css 3 ?

Comment: IE is just slow to support newer languages so sometimes we need to use tools like css3Pie to manipulate the browser in such a way that it does what you want. The only way to get IE to understand gradients is with javascript or the tools that @Kolyunya and I have suggested.

Comment: the thing is I put PIE.htc everywhere in the website, I can't make it work, I have the right path, I can see it in chrome with the inspect element. But on IE, nothing happen ...I've uploaded the site, you can check it by yourself if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not support CSS3, but you can use some JavaScript tools to emulate it's work, e.g.

- http://css3pie.com/
- http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/

Comment: yeah but IE isn't supposed to understand that css 3 ?